# React Native Debugger Won't Turn Off

Tags: debugging, react-native, remote-debugging

I was using the React Native Debugger on a Mac. However, after I pressed Cmd + D entered Stop Remote JS Debugging, and then hit reload, the application won't quit popping up the debugging screen in Chrome every time I tried to refresh.

I've tried turning off the simulator and killing all the ports/pids. I've also tried exiting out of Chrome, but nothing works.

How do you turn off the Remote Debugging in React Native?